# How can I know if an element is empty in my translation file in my html component?

Tags: angular, translation, ngx-translate

I use ngx-translate, I create files : **en.json** and **fr.json** in order to translate in french and english.

In **en.json** :

```
{
    "home": {
        "test": ""
    }
}
```

In **fr.json** :

```
{
    "home": {
        "test": "Testons"
    }
}
```

The user browser language is English ( en ) but the default web site language is French.

I want to do something in order to allow me to use french if the translation path is empty. I know that the translation could work if I didn't have **home.test** path  , but I don't want to do that.

Is possible to allow me to use french even if the translation path is empty ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement `TranslateLoader` to change to do what you want.

For example this one removes empty strings from the files (of course, you can adapt it depending your needs):
**my-translate-loader.ts**

```js
export class MyTranslateLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private prefix: string = '/assets/i18n/',
    private suffix: string = '.json') {
  }

  public getTranslation(lang: string): any {
    return this.http.get(`${this.prefix}${lang}${this.suffix}`)
      .pipe(map(result => this.process(result)));
  }

  private process(object: object) {
    return Object.keys(object)
      .filter(key => object.hasOwnProperty(key) && object[key] !== '')
      .reduce((result, key) => (result[key] = typeof object[key] === 'object' ? this.process(object[key]) : object[key], result), {});
  }
}
```

And then in your `app.module.ts` file, change the following:

```js
// required for AOT compilation
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new MyTranslateLoader(http);
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Assuming you have already configured your module imports like this:

```js
imports: [
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
      deps: [HttpClient]
    }
  })
  ...
]
```